# Using .replace() while looping through dictionary - Why code 1 doesn't work and code 2 does?

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

Howdy: I am somewhat of a programming/python newbie. I have just been trying to create a simple script that loops through a dictionary and replaces the dictionary keys with their associated values for text in a text file. My first code didn't work, and I don't understand why. Here it is

```
replacements = {'Bob': 'John', 'Betty': 'Brenda'}

def main():
    with open('end_words_list.txt', 'r+') as article:
        read_article = article.read()
        for ending, replacement in replacements.iteritems():
            replaced = read_article.replace(ending, replacement)
            article.seek(0)
            article.write(replaced)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code gives this error when I run it `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

So I decided to rewrite the code with 2 functions in which I separate the dictionary looping from the actually writing to file, to see if that works. And it did. Here is the code:

```
replacements = {'Bob': 'John.', 
                'Betty': 'Brenda'}

def search_and_replace(ending, replacement):
    with open('end_words_list.txt', 'r+') as article:
        read_article = article.read()
        replaced = read_article.replace(ending, replacement)
        article.seek(0)
        article.write(replaced)

def main():
    for ending, replacement in replacements.iteritems():
        search_and_replace(ending, replacement)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am still baffled, however, why the first code doesn't work. Why is text file seen as closed when trying to write to it, when the code so closely resembles that in the 2nd code that works?

EDIT: oops forgot to add contents of text file before writing to it:

`I got a friend called Bob, and a friend called Betty. Bob is nice, but Betty is nicer.`

EDIT 2: Adding full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]  File "D:\Magic Briefcase\My Python Scripts\Spin Scripts\End Words\End_Words.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Magic Briefcase\My Python Scripts\Spin Scripts\End Words\End_Words.py", line 8, in main
    article.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback, not just a description of the error.

Comment: I added full traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing tabs and spaces in your code, so that what looks like correct indentation to you looks completely different to the interpreter.

In particular, you use tabs for the first two lines of the `main` function, but spaces for the rest. Because the interpreter treats a tab as indenting 8 spaces (unlike StackOverflow, and presumably your editor, which treat them as indenting 4 spaces, or jumping to the next tab stop), it's seeing your code like this:

```
def main():
        with open('end_words_list.txt', 'r+') as article:
                read_article = article.read()
        for ending, replacement in replacements.iteritems():
            replaced = read_article.replace(ending, replacement)
            article.seek(0)
            article.write(replaced)
```

---

If you're using something like Notepad or TextEdit as your editor, switch to almost anything else. Most other editors have a way to turn all your tabs into spaces, or show tabs explicitly, or in some other way solve this problem.

Also, try running your code with the -tt flag, which will give you a clear error when it detects that you've unexpectedly switched from tabs to spaces or vice-versa, instead of silently misinterpreting your code.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am using sublime text 2 and I have it set up to change spaces to tabs, so not sure how I got such a spacing mess, but I did! Also the "-tt flag" is not something I have come across before. I just tried to google it and did a search within python docs, but I did not see anything come up for it. Is there somewhere I can read about this?

Comment: @Darren don't replace spaces with tabs. replace tabs with spaces. tabs are evil. [Pep-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

Comment: Scrap that, I need to learn how to google better. Taking the "-" out of "-tt" and searching for "tt flag python" brought up some results

Comment: @mhlester I was confused about. I thought I had changed things so that spaces are replaced with tabs, but I didn't. Thinking about it now, that would be a crazy things to do. However, I will now adjust sublime text from `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,` to `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,`

Answer (score 1):

abarnert's answer is the correct one (*I'm pretty sure it always is :)* ), but I'd like to address two more issue as well:

- There's no need to write `replaced` back to `article` until you've replaced all of them. Take that out of the for-loop.
- You're replacing one word at a time, saving that to a variable, then replacing the next word from your *original* string rather than the updated. Modify the same variable each time, storing it in place so it's ready for the next iteration.

So your code should be:

```
def main():
    with open('end_words_list.txt', 'r+') as article:
        read_article = article.read()
        for ending, replacement in replacements.iteritems():
            read_article = read_article.replace(ending, replacement)
        article.seek(0)
        article.write(read_article)
```

Note that I've changed the assignment from `replaced` to `read_article`, and I've taken the `seek` and `write` out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for that. Much nicer and more efficient!

Comment: I just tried that code and my original one (my code 1), and neither of them actually work correctly because they only replace the very last iteration in the dictionary loop. My code 2 works ok though, because each iteration is replaced, even though the file has to be continually opened and closed. Not sure that ca be avoided, and I would rather not import regex and go the re.sub route.

Comment: @Darren, it's working for me. There should never be a need to write a variable to disk every time you modify it